# Redirecting dev site to live site on same server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Before anyone suggests, I've already tried various solutions, but none seem to do anything correctly.

I basically have a server which has site files on, which are both accessible via a dev URL and now the live URL. However, Google still indexes the development URL, so I want to add a 301 redirect in the htaccess file so that any clicks on the dev site URL goes to live, this includes internal pages too.

The site is Wordpress, so there are existing htaccess rules. This is what I've done so far:

```
RewriteRule ^http://mydevsite\.co\.uk\.172-24-16-212\.server6\.co\.uk(.*)$ mylivesite.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it works, but only for the home page. So I tried for a specific page:

```
RewriteRule ^http://mydevsite\.co\.uk\.172-24-16-212\.server6\.co\.uk/galleries/ mylivesite.co.uk/galleries/ [R=301,L]
```

But this just doesn't work.

I'm not an expert at 301 redirects, so if someone can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guesing that you already tried this, but if you are using bluehost as a hosting service, you should be able to redirect traffic by going to the domains menu, then the redirect sub-menu where you can fill the appropriate fields. If you are not using bluehost then I don't know enough to help :/

[This link has more information.](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/redirects)

Comment: No, it's Rackspace actually - but I'm working on a solution.